# How to replace header text in a word file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, header

I am trying to write a code that creates a new file from template file and replaces certain words (titles, document number, project numbers etc.) with a table in excel.

I have currently been able to google my to find this code. It is It currently only changes the project names (written with /PROJ/ as placeholder in template). Currently just a test.
However, it does not pick up the project name in the header.
Any solution?

```
Public Sub WordFindAndReplace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
With msWord
.Visible = True
.Activate

.Documents.Add "C:\Users\*User*\Documents\Custom Office Templates\MRB_Template.dotx"


        With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
                .Text = "/PROJ/"
                .Replacement.Text = ws.Range("I1").Value2
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

I have also tried to insert bookmarks and replace that, but it still isnt able to pick up bookmarks in the header.

Comment: Research the use of mapped content controls as this is a much better solution when you need the same data in multiple places in the document. This has the advantage that changing one instance of the data updates all of the others. You can either create your own, in which case you add an xml part to the document template, or repurpose the built-in ones found under Insert | Quick Parts | Document Property.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate through all sections to find all headers to do this.

Add this snippet

```
    For Each Section In .ActiveDocument.Sections
        For Each Header In Section.Headers
            With Header.Range.Find
                    .Text = "/PROJ/"
                    .Replacement.Text = ws.Range("I1").Value2
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                .Execute Replace:=2     'wdReplaceAll (WdReplace Enumeration)
            End With

        Next
    Next
```

before or after your other replace. This is the same replace, but once for every header in your document.